# IE issue with styling <select/> element

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Consider the following HTML markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title>search/master</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            select{
                background-color: pink;
            }
            option{
                background-color: white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>
            <select>
                <option>one........</option>
                <option>two........</option>
            </select> 
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Output on FF as follows: (Similar output comes on Chrome, Safari and Opera as well)

[image: output on FF & other browsers]

But output on IE as follows:

[image: output on IE]

What is the reliable and simple workaround to make the output on IE looks similar to other browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you definitely want to do this, you could use a 1px x 1px background image, and set the option to `:transparent`

```
select{
    background: url(http://ajthomas.co.uk/stackoverflow-help/back.png);
}
option{
    background: transparent;
}
```

See the [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7ndVE/) i have done for you

Comment: A very apt use of the word _defiantly_.

Answer (score 1):

If you make both background color( for select and option) pink, it looks exactly the same in every browser. A better solution maybe..do not specify the background color on the option element at all....

Comment: "If you make both background color( for select and option) pink, it looks exactly the same in every browser" No it dosent, the 'select' will be white in IE!

Comment: Well..I'm using ie9 and it looks normal. Maybe you are using an older version?

Comment: Of course you are wright, I do apologize. But my requirement is to keep the 'select' and 'option' in different colors.

Comment: @MISS_DUKE: so than in this case it looks like FireFox (and others except ie) are acting strange.

Answer (score 1):

- First remove the following css value, it's giving the OPTIONS a white background color and thus hiding the select's pink background color in IE.

  ```
  option {
      background-color: white;
  }
  ```
- Second always enclose Form elements inside the Form and Fieldset tag like shown below:-

  ```html
  <form>
  <fieldset>
      <select>
          <option>One</option>
      </select>
  </fieldset>
  </form>
  ```
- Third Form and Fieldset have a default border and padding values so in css you can add this code to remove those default values:

  ```
  form, fieldset {
      border: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
  }
  ```

So in short the main reason for IE not displaying the Select Box correctly is because the select element isn't enclosed in FORM and the OPTION's White background color value.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when we specify some background color for the options inside the select element and the select element itself.

**Workaround :** Apply style (background-color) to the option elements only when the select element is in focussed state. ( it is only during focussed state of the select element we actually see the option elements inside it )

```
 select{
     background-color: #f1f1f1;
     ...              
  }

  select:focus > *{
    background-color:#fff;
  }
```